# Como usar colormaps de matplotlib con strings?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Estoy intentando representar en una grafica diferentes datos. Supongamos que tengo en una carpeta los siguientes archivos .csv, nombrados como Car_1, Car_2...Car_n, Tree_1, Tree_2...Tree_n.
Me gustaría usar un *colormap* para cada set de archivos que tiene el mismo nombre, y así poder distinguir los datos más facilmente/intuitivamente.

Con el siguiente código soy capaz de realizar tal acción.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pylab as plt
import re

DATE = '2020-06-12'

MainFolder = 'D:/' + DATE + '/' + 'Figures' + '/'
os.chdir(MainFolder)

print('\n' + 'You are working on this directory: \n', os.getcwd(), '\n')

def atoi(text):
    return int(text) if text.isdigit() else text

def natural_keys(text):
    return [atoi(c) for c in re.split(r'(\d+)', text)]

print('The files in the directory are:')
print('-------------------------------')
filenames = []
labels     = []
for file in sorted(os.listdir(), key=natural_keys, reverse=False):
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        filenames.append(file)
        labels.append(os.path.splitext(file)[0])
        print('    ' + file)
print('-------------------------------')

datas = []

for filename in filenames:
    datas.append(pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(filename)))

print('Total number of files: '+ str(len(filenames)))

def Plot():

plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, sharex=True, figsize=[15,9], facecolor='white', dpi=100)

# Find ocurrences  in labels
Car_times = sum('Car' in s for s in labels)
Tree_Times = sum('Tree' in s for s in labels)
Phone_Times = sum('Phone' in s for s in labels)
Dog_Times = sum('Dog' in s for s in labels)

# Assign as many colours as ocurrences 
Car_Colors = plt.cm.Spectral(np.linspace(0,1, Car_times))
Tree_Colors = plt.cm.Greens_r(np.linspace(0,1, Tree_Times))
Phone_Colors = plt.cm.Greys_r(np.linspace(0,1,Phone_Times))
Dog_Colors = plt.cm.Reds_r(np.linspace(0,1,Dog_Times))

# Join arrays
colors     =  [*Car_Colors, *Tree_Colors, *Phone_Colors, *Dog_Colors]  
linestyles = []
for label in labels:
    if 'Car' in label:
        linestyles.append('solid')
    elif 'Tree' in label:
        linestyles.append('solid')
    elif 'Phone' in label:
        linestyles.append('solid')
    elif 'Dog' in label:
        linestyles.append('solid')

plt.subplot(111)
count = 0
for data in datas:
    plt.semilogx(data['X'], data['Y'], marker='o', color=colors[count], label=labels[count], markersize=3, linestyle = linestyles[count])
    count = count + 1
    plt.ylabel('Y-Axis')
    plt.xlabel('X-Axis')
    plt.grid(True, which='both')
    plt.legend(loc='best', fontsize=8)
plt.show()

Plot()
```

Sin embargo me parece un poco tedioso como esta ordenado. Siendo un poco más específico, mis archivos estan ordenados alfabeticamente, por lo que en el array *colors* tengo que añadir el colormap en la posición determinada (Supongamos que tuviera otros archivos llamados Cat_1, Cat_2...Cat_n)

Sabe alguien, como podría mejorar o adaptar esta parte?. Es decir, que no tenga que añadir el colormap en la posición determinada.

Muchas gracias!